# Multiple condition in 'for' loop is not working in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to print all occurring even numbers up to 20. The code is working fine with an *if* condition, but it is not working with multiple conditions in the loop.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    for(int i = 1; ((i <= 20) && (i % 2 == 0)); i ++)
        cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: `1 % 2` is not equal 0, so your loop condition is false on the very first iteration

Comment: It is working fine. In the first iteration `i=1`, second condition is not fulfilled, loop is never entered.

Comment: for works until your condition is true, but when i = 1 your condition is false, so you go out from for

Comment: Can you please get into the habit of _investigating_ bugs in your one-line programs?  You could very easily experiment with these conditions, write a loop that outputs what `(i%2)` is, etc.  Or attach a debugger and step through the loop.  If you develop the habit of coming online to post a question any time something remotely unexpected happens while programming, your growth is going to be extremely limited.

Comment: Separate loop and print condition. Or you may use for(int i = 2; i <= 20; i+=2)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but removing all the parentheses from `((i <= 20) && (i % 2 == 0))` doesn't change what it does. But it makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing two different things. When you want your loop to stop, and when you want to print a number.

In the code you have written you've put the 'when you want to print a number' condition where you should only have the 'when you want your loop to stop' condition. Because of this, as soon as you get an odd number, your loop stops.

Your code should be

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i ++)
    if (i % 2 == 0)
       cout << i << endl;
```

Comment: @super And why should it be ? OP's loop starts from `1`, not `0`. I don't see here the need to change the OP's requirements.

Comment: @super *i* never value 0 because min value is 1, so why are you speaking about that ?

Comment: @super _"...up to 20"_ I don't see here any "from zero" mention. And if we read the code, it is clear that OP wants to start from 1. Moreover, replacing the start value 1 with 0 doesn't change the validity of this answer. So your comment is a bit irrelevant :)

Comment: @super *up to 20* can also start from -infinite or using `int` from `INT_MIN` if you do not want to consider OP *i* initialization, so why speaking about 0 ? I cannot understand your thought ...

Comment: @super the only *natural* thing is to work with `int i = 1` from OP code